# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error C beginner program

Tags: c, xcode

I am learning C and when I copy the tutorial code into *Xcode* it works. I tried to write my own simple I/O. The goal of the program is to ask input for each variable, `a, b, c`, etc. When I try to run my code the terminal says (`11db`) then I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error and a warning that there are more `%` conversions than data arguments. Not sure what the problem is as I entered code almost identical to what the tutorial used. I used `int` variable since the idea is `1+2+3`. I tried to place `sum = a + b + c` both before and after the `printf` and `scanf` functions and neither have worked. I am at a loss for what is causing this to occur. I did notice that in my feedback window

```
a (int) 33234 b = (int) 32766 c = (int) -272632304 sum = (int) 0
```

I am not sure how `b` and `c` were populated as it stops after the first data entry. Help is appreciated.

---

**Tutorial Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    float a; 
    int b; 
    char ch;

    printf("\nEnter value of float\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("\nEnter value of int\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("\nEnter value of char\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);

    printf("\nValue of float : %f", a);
    printf("\nValue of int : %d", b);
    printf("\nValue of char : %c", ch);
    printf("\nValue of float(rounded) : %.2f\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int sum;

    printf("\nEnter value of a\n");
    scanf("%d , &a");

    printf("\nEnter value of b\n");
    scanf("%d , &b");

    printf("\nEnter value of c\n");
    scanf("%d , &c");

    sum = "a + b + c";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I didn't even realize that thank you. I am still having issues getting the sum. It now flows through like it should, but doesn't produce a sum.

Comment: I was about to come back and fix that comment. I ran it and it went smooth and I now have no errors. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrections are in comments.  I also added a `printf()` call to display the sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int sum;

    printf("\nEnter value of a\n");
    scanf("%d", &a); /* moved &a out of quotes */

    printf("\nEnter value of b\n");
    scanf("%d", &b); /* moved &b out of quotes */

    printf("\nEnter value of c\n");
    scanf("%d", &c); /* moved &c out of quotes */

    sum = a + b + c; /* got rid of quotes altogether */
    printf("%d + %d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c, sum); /* added to display results */

    return 0;

}
```

Give that a try and see if it works better for you.  C uses (") quotes to enclose a string constant.  Such a constant is just data, not code. "a + b + c" doesn't do anything.  It's just a bunch of characters. (You'll find out later that's actually an array of `char` values, with and extra binary 0 byte as an end marker. That's important, but it's not today's lesson.)

Comment: I fixed it , but your code looks a lot better. So  it doesn't matter if int sum is right above sum = portion or at top, but which is more professional and cleaner?

Comment: @Exodus5656 Where to declare variables is at least partly a matter of style.  One modern tendency is to not declare a variable until you have a meaningful value to assign it. Others use what used to be a requirement in C, putting all declarations at the top of the outermost block that actually uses the name.  Like indentation style and variable naming conventions, there are different styles.  Pick one and stick with it for any program or project.  If something rubs the wrong way, try something else on the next program.

Comment: @Exodus5656 By the way, if you copied the earlier version, there was an error that "commented out" the assignment to sum altogether.  (Not very professional on my part. <blush>) Anyway, this should be better.

Comment: I actually prefer the way the it looks when the int sum is after the values have already been gathered directly above sum =. It is easier for me to read and I think that might be better when I debug in the future. I did notice that after I did it the way you did it there were errors. Specifically that the value had not been assigned and when I let Xcode fix the error it broke the code.. haha. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I tried, but the arrows to upvote didn't show up when I hovered over the comment. The only thing I can do is flag, but those clearly don't deserve a flag.

Comment: Upvoting comments and flagging requires 15 reputation. I am greatly appreciative of all the help that both of you have provided.